# Check whether an expression is valid using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to check if a string is a valid math expression. Allowed operations are +,-,*,/ and ^. I tried this and don't know why it doesn't work:

```
a = raw_input("Unesite izraz")
if len( re.findall(r'(\d+(?:.\d+)?(?: [\+\-\/\*\^]\d+(?:.\d+) )* )', a ) ) != 0:
```

But this regex expression returns [] for valid expressions. Why? Thanks!

Comment: Not really an answer, but when you match a number `\d+(?:.\d+)?`, the dot should be escaped as `\.`, since otherwise `'1a3'` and `'9(10'` would be considered valid numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A validator for a simple symbol math expression could be something like this.
This would be a 1 time match of the entire string.

`^\s*[+-]?\s*(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:\s*[-+/*^]\s*\s*[+-]?\s*(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+))*\s*$`

Formatted:

```
 ^                             # BOS
 \s* [+-]? \s*                 # whitespace (opt), sign (opt), whitespace (opt)
 (?:                           # Integer or decimal
      \d+ 
      (?: \. \d* )?
   |  \. \d+ 
 )
 (?:                           # Cluster group
      \s* [-+/*^] \s*               # whitespace (opt), operation symbol (req'd), whitespace (opt)
      \s* [+-]? \s*                 # whitespace (opt), sign (opt), whitespace (opt)
      (?:                           # Integer or decimal
           \d+ 
           (?: \. \d* )?
        |  \. \d+ 
      )
 )*                            # End cluster, do 0 to many times
 \s*                           # optional whitespace
 $                             # EOS
```

Comment: This works, thanks, but shouldn't we use \ in front of +,- etc.

Comment: The `+` is inside a character class where its not a quantifier .. no need to escape it. Likewise the `*` and`^`.

Answer (score 1):

You have spaces in the wrong places.

```
# yours / fixed
r'(\d+(?:.\d+)?(?: [\+\-\/\*\^]\d+(?:.\d+) )* )'
r'(\d+(?:.\d+)?(?: [\+\-\/\*\^] \d+(?:.\d+) )*)'
```

You can try them at [pythex.org](http://pythex.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your regexp.

There is the operator "except": `[^abc]`
Thus, it will take whatever is not the characters "a", "b" or "c".

```
import re

e1 = '1 + 2' # correct
e2 = '1 + 3 * 3 / 6 ^ 2' # correct
e3 = '1 + 3 x 3' # wrong

el = [e1, e2, e3]
regexp = re.compile(r'[^+\-*\/^0-9\s]')
for i in el:
    if len(regexp.findall(i)):
        print(i, 'wrong')
    else:
        print(i, 'correct')
```

You can use this site to learn and test yours regexp: https://regex101.com/